# Determine the set on which series converges

Tags: calculus

Find the MacLaurin series for the below and determine the set on which it converges.
$ln(1+x+x^2+x^3)$

I have tried finding MacLaurin series by method $$ln(1+x+x^2+x^3)= (x+x^2+x^3)+\frac{(x+x^2+x^3)^2}{2}+\ldots$$
I am not able to proceed further and find set of points on which it converges

Comment: I would find for which values of $x$ does $\log(1+x)$ converge and then substitute $x$ by $x+x^2+x^3$.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. It worked @Zanzag